# Light linking not showing up

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, shadows

I've got Blender 4.0.2 but there is no Light Linking or Shadow Linking in the object properties. There's not even the 'Shading' tab. Any ideas why? Does it need enabling?

Comment: Do you have a light selected in the outliner? - It's there on this machine under the Shading dropdown. This is the Blender [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/light_linking.html#light-linking) entry about light linking.

Comment: Are you using Cycles and not another render engine?